# How to return a value using only instance name

Tags: ruby

I have a class called `Test`. I've created an instance:

```
example = Test.new
```

I want to return a value when I type this:

```
example
```

I know how to return a value when typing:

```
example.give_me_some_stuff
```

But I can't figure out how to override just the instance name and return some value, preferably the result of a method inside of the class.

EDIT:

This works for a method that returns a string, but I can't return an instance variable from the instance of the class. For example here is the test I'm trying to make work:

```
  def test_push
    stack = Stack.new
    stack.push(10)
    binding.pry
    refute stack.empty?
  end
```

And here is my class:

```
class Stack
  attr_accessor :contents

  def inspect
    @contents
  end

  def initialize
     @contents = []
  end

  def push(n)
    @contents << n
  end

end
```

In the test my object comes back as:

```
#<Stack:0x007f8cd9051938 @contents=[10]>
```

When I want it to return just the value of @contents.

Comment: I don't think this is reasonable. As you know, #new is a constructor. Constructor always return an instance of the class. So your idea is pointless.

Answer (score 2):

`example` always returns your object. If it would return another object, `example.give_me_some_stuff` would not work anymore.

Maybe you're looking for [`inspect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Object.html#method-i-inspect). IRB calls `inspect` when printing your object:

```
class Test
  def inspect
    "I am Test"
  end
end
```

IRB session:

```
irb(main):001:0> example = Test.new
=> I am Test
irb(main):002:0> example
=> I am Test
```

Comment: This works for a string but it won't return the value of an instance method if  I put it in there. I've updated the question with the exact code I'm trying to get to pass.

Comment: @Corey `inspect` is supposed to return a string. In your example, returning `@contents.inspect` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean this?:

```
Test = Struct.new('Test', :a, :b)
example = Test.new(1, 2)
example.instance_eval do
  def give_me_some_stuff
    a + b
  end
end

example.give_me_some_stuff #=> 3
another_example = Test.new(1, 2)
# => #<struct Struct::Test a=1, b=2>
another_example.give_me_some_stuff
#=> NoMethodError: undefined method `give_me_some_stuff' for #<struct Struct::Test a=1, b=2>
```